# WinDbg get addresses of all functions from symbols

Tags: c#, windbg

Executing command `x ShittyProject!*` I am getting such output

```
<MSIL:00250014         > ShittyProject!Main (void)
<MSIL:00250098         > ShittyProject!.ctor (void)
<MSIL:00250037         > ShittyProject!.ctor (void)
<MSIL:002500ed         > ShittyProject!get_Default (void)
<MSIL:002500a1         > ShittyProject!get_ResourceManager (void)
<MSIL:002500f8         > ShittyProject!.cctor (void)
<MSIL:0025002a         > ShittyProject!Foo (void)
<MSIL:0025006e         > ShittyProject!InitializeComponent (void)
<MSIL:00250000         > ShittyProject!InitializeComponent (void)
<MSIL:002500da         > ShittyProject!get_Culture (void)
<MSIL:002500e5         > ShittyProject!set_Culture (void)
```

If I understand correct `MSIL:*` it is only adress of function in `pdb` file?
Is it possible somehow to get addresses of the function to place breakpoints on them?

Comment: Before you can get a "normal" breakpoint the code needs to be JIT compiled which happens upon first execution of your application. What you needs is part of sos.dll and called managed breakpoint !bpmd. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774964/setting-breakpoint-in-windbg-sos-with-generically-typed-classes

Comment: @AloisKraus, please provide example I tried but debugger did not stopped. Many thanks.

Comment: !sos.bpmd is the regular (and easiest) way to do this. However, if the method has already been JITed, you can manually place a breakpoint on the address just like native code. For example, use !sos.name2ee <dll>!<full method name> to list the method details. If JITed, the actual address is given. Then you can do bp <JIT address> to place a breakpoint on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed code is different from native code. To set breakpoints the "native way" (`bp`), you would need to wait until the method is JIT-compiled and then use the native address of the method.

Normally, one would not do that, but use .NET specific equivalents instead. There is [SOS (Microsoft docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sos-dll-sos-debugging-extension) `!bpmd` or [SOSEX](http://www.stevestechspot.com/) (probably no longer maintained) `!mbm`.

Given the code

```
using System;

namespace JittyProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You want to stop before this shows up.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

You want to stop at the initial breakpoint and tell it to wait until .NET is loaded, e.g.

```
0:000> sxe ld clr
0:000> g
```

Once the .NET runtime is loaded, you can load the SOS extension for .NET specific debugging commands.

```
0:000> .loadby sos clr
```

And the SOSEX extension:

```
0:000> .load c:\wherever\SOSEX.dll
```

And then add a breakpoint:

```
0:000> !mbm JittyProject.Program.Main
```

Using the regular `g`, you'll eventually hit the breakpoint:

```
0:000> g
ModLoad: 76650000 766e2000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OLEAUT32.dll
Breakpoint: JIT notification received for method JittyProject.Program.Main() in AppDomain 00960db0.
Breakpoint set at JittyProject.Program.Main() in AppDomain 00960db0.
Breakpoint 2 hit

0:000> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x3ff8 (0)
Child SP       IP Call Site
003eeda0 77601ffc [PrestubMethodFrame: 003eeda0] JittyProject.Program.Main() [C:\...\JittyProject\Program.cs @ 8]
003eef74 77601ffc [GCFrame: 003eef74]
```

Comment: is it possible to pass to `!bpmd` adress of functions instead of name?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @A191919: a) no, I don't know a way of using the MSIL address to achieve the same thing b) I changed my answer because I could not reproduce the debugging session 4 times in a row. !bpmd seems not so reliable